# How to plot a grid of histograms with Matplotlib in the order of the DataFrame columns?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

Considers the simple data frame below:

```
import pandas  as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'var3':[1,3,9,6,1,6,3,1,1,3],
                   'var1':[9,1,2,6,6,5,9,3,1,7],
                   'var2':[6,6,2,9,8,3,5,4,1,3]})
df
```

[image]

Now, let's plot a set of histograms from this data:

```
df.hist(layout=(1,3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the order (from left to right) of the histograms in the figure is different from the order of the columns in the data frame. How to make the histograms obey the order of its data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to do that within the `df.hist()` function. But you can accomplish it with the simple loop below:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(df.columns), figsize=(3*len(df.columns), 3))
for i, var in enumerate(df):
    df[var].hist(ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set_title(var)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like @foglerit's answer, but here's another workaround solution:

```py
import pandas  as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'var3':[1,3,9,6,1,6,3,1,1,3],
                   'var1':[9,1,2,6,6,5,9,3,1,7],
                   'var2':[6,6,2,9,8,3,5,4,1,3]})

columns = df.columns  # save original column names
columns_temp = []  # create temporary column names, numbered
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    columns_temp.append('(' + str(i+1) + ') ' + str(col))
df.columns = columns_temp

df.hist(layout=(1,3))  # now the column order is not messed up

df.columns = columns  # reassign original column names
```

[image: df.hist plot]